# Collect Max Coins From An Array In 2 Consecutive Intervals

Tags: java, algorithm, math, data-structures

Given an array A consisting of N integers denoting the number of `coins` on each `box` in
the row, and integers K and L denoting, respectively, the number of boxes that `robo1 and robo2` can
choose when collecting, returns the maximum number of coins that can be collected by them, or -1
if there are no such intervals.

> For example, given A = [6, 1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4], K = 3, L = 2, your
> function should return 24, because robo1 can choose boxes 3 to 5 and
> collect 4 + 6 + 3 = 13 coins, and robo2 can choose boxes 7 to 8 and
> collect  7 +4 = 11 coins. Thus, they will collect 13 + 11 = 24 coins
> in total, and that is the maximum  number that can be achieved.
>
> Given A = [10, 19, 15], K = 2, L = 2, your function should return -1,
> because it is not possible for robo1 and robo2 to choose two disjoint
> intervals.

I have written below function to collect max coins.

```
public static int getMaxCoins(int[] A, int K, int L) {

    if(A.length<K+L)
        return -1;
    
    int highest = 0;
    int lowest = 0;

    if(K>L){
        highest = K;
        lowest = L;
    }
    
    int robo1Coins = 0;       
    int remainingArray[] = null;
    int part1[];
    int part2[];
    
    int robo2Coins = 0;
    
    for(int i=0;i+highest<=A.length;i++){
        int[] sub = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, i, i+highest);
        int count = IntStream.of(sub).sum();
        if(count>robo1Coins) {
            robo1Coins = count;
            part1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, i);
            part2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, i+highest, A.length);
            remainingArray = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(part1), Arrays.stream(part2)).toArray();
        }            
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i+lowest<=remainingArray.length;i++){
        int[] sub = Arrays.copyOfRange(remainingArray, i, i+lowest);
        int count = IntStream.of(sub).sum();
        if(count>robo2Coins) {
            robo2Coins = count;
        }            
    }
    
    System.out.println("Robo1 Coins - "+robo1Coins+" Robo2 Coins-"+robo2Coins);

return robo1Coins+robo2Coins;
}
```

The above solution is working fine for the given cases.

> But I feel my solution has few problems
>
> 1. Not optimistic/Less performant
> 2. Failing on edge cases
> 3. Not following any algorithmic approach

*Please help to point out. What is the right approaches/algorithms available to solve this in more efficient manner.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem with a sliding window algorithm. The window's length should be `K+L`. Imagine robo1 leading, and robo2 following behind as they march across the array.

As the window moves you need to update separate sums for each robot: `sum1` and `sum2`. You also need to keep track of the best sum seen by the trailing robot: `best2`, and the best combined sum: `bestCombined`.

After each window move, update the best results:

```
best2=max(best2, sum2) 
bestCombined=max(bestCombined, best2+sum1)
```

When the sliding window reaches the end of the array, `bestCombined` is one of two possible answers. Swap the robots, and run the algorithm again to find the other possible answer.

---

Here's a sample run of the algorithm.
**First with robo1 leading (blue) and robo2 following (red):**

[image]

**Then with robo2 leading, and robo1 following:**
[image]

The best combined score is 24 which is achieved with robo2 leading.